# SQL Server : select count of Todays Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I was wondering if someone could help me as I can't seem to find an answer to the following that I have been searching for.

```
Select 
    Count(pm1.number) As number 
From 
    SCenter.probsummarym1 As pm1 
Where 
    pm1.open_time >= Today()
```

I have the above that works great if I put in the date as '01-05-2015'

But I want today's date each day when it refreshes.

Sorry if this is pretty basic but I am just lost on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GETDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) will return the current date and time.

You may then use a [CAST() or CONVERT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to strip the time value and be left with just the date, ie.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
```

The above code would return **05-19-2015** for today.

```
Select 
  Count(pm1.number) As number 
From SCenter.probsummarym1 As pm1 

Where 
  pm1.open_time >= GETDATE()  //or CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
```

Comment: I used the CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) instead of just GETDATE() as this works perfectly...